# Feign Hystrix fallback not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I have the below FeignClient:

```
@FeignClient(name="FooMS",fallback=CustomerFeign.CustomerFeignImpl.class)
public interface CustomerFeign {

    @RequestMapping(value="/bar/{phoneNo}")
    List<Long> getFriends(@PathVariable("phoneNo") Long phoneNo);


    class CustomerFeignImpl implements CustomerFeign{

        @Override
        public List<Long> getFriends(Long phoneNo) {
            return new ArrayList<Long>(108);
        }

    }

}
```

When the FooMS instance is down, I get a 500 error instead of the fallback being executed. Why is this happening?

Comment: could you share your stack trace ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag your `CustomerFeignImpl` as a `@Component` or create a `@Bean` out of it.

Comment: Thanks. I also had to add the feign.hystrix.enabled=true property. I found that I am not able to modify the hystrix timeout through property files. Even if I give, hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=50000 or hystrix.command.getFriends.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=50000, hystrix with Feign still timesout in 1 sec. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Hi, Is this answer valid with latest version cloud 2020.0.3 ? I am getting java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information error.  I have feign.hystrix.enabled=true + interface  @FeignClient(name="verbservice", fallback = VerbClientFallback.class) public interface VerbClient { ....} +  another class @Component
public class VerbClientFallback implements VerbClient { ...}

Comment: @KrisSwat Could you try to use `feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true` property instead? That worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

adding @Component and feign.hystrix.enabled=true works fine

Answer (score 4):

This works for me with `2020.0.3`:

In `application.properties`

```
feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true
```

In `pom.xml`

```
 <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @rostlvan, I was able to get this working. Have posted my implementation as an answer. Please check it out.

Comment: The feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true was the trick. 
In previous versions, we had feign.hystrix.enabled=true, which was renamed (to accept multiple circuit breaker implementations) in this commit https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/commit/63a524843d3cfb9c6c1de45ca6cff5e1ea6e6a26

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [rostlvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10463949/rostivan)!

I am outlining my implementation below:

I am using Spring Cloud version `2020.0.4` and the following configuration worked for me:

in `pom.xml`, I have these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Though I'm not sure if we need to have both `openfeign` and `hystrix` dependencies. Someone can validate that!

In my `application.properties` I have `feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true`

In my Main Application class, I have

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class MySpringBootApplication{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
   }

 }
```

And finally, my Feign Client, fallback and fallback factory:

`UserServiceFeignClient.java`

```
@FeignClient(name = "USER-SERVICE", fallbackFactory = UserServiceFallbackFactory.class)
public interface UserServiceFeignClient {
    
    @GetMapping("/api/users/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable String userId);
}
```

`UserServiceFeignClientFallback.java`

```
public class UserServiceFeignClientFallback implements UserServiceFeignClient{
    
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(String userId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new User());
    }
}
```

And, `UserServiceFeignClientFallbackFactory.java`:

```
@Component
public class UserServiceFallbackFactory implements FallbackFactory<UserServiceFeignClientFallback>{

    @Override
    public UserServiceFeignClientFallback create(Throwable cause) {
        return new UserServiceFeignClientFallback();
    }
    
}
```

Was facing the problem myself, until I stumbled upon the answer from [@rostlvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10463949/rostivan)