# Feign - Hystrix - feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: no further information executing GET

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

I have

```
@FeignClient(name="verbservice", fallback = VerbClientFallback.class)
public interface VerbClient {
    @GetMapping
    public String getVerbWord();
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class VerbClientFallback implements VerbClient {
    @Override
    public String getVerbWord() {
        return "fallback";
    }
}
```

App

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableHystrix
public class SentenceAppApplication {
...}
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
private VerbClient verbClient;
....
return verbClient.getVerbWord() + ....other;
```

application.properties

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=true
```

Versions

> Spring boot 2.5.4

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

**Goal: stop the verb service and see if fallback is invoked or not.**

Problem:

> nested exception is feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: no
> further information executing GET http://verbservice] with root cause

I tried steps in this link...but it is not working
[Feign Hystrix fallback not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428434/feign-hystrix-fallback-not-working)

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: nope. haven't tried again

Comment: feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true  works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the property

> feign.hystrix.enabled=true

is changed to

> feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true